# How do I determine the path to a binary of a process?

Tags: process

Is there a way to find out the directory/disk location a process was started from? I am aware of the /proc mount but not really where to look inside of it.

Comment: Do you mean the location of the binary, or the directory from which a process started?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I mean the binary

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `/proc` way would be to inspect the `exe` link in the directory corresponding to the pid.

Let's take an example with `update-notifier`:

Find the pid, which is *15421* in this example:

```
egil@gud:~$ ps x | grep update-notifier
 2405 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep update-notifier
15421 ?        Sl     0:00 update-notifier
```

Look up the symbolic link:

```
egil@gud:~$ file /proc/15421/exe
/proc/15421/exe: symbolic link to `/usr/bin/update-notifier'
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I was almost there. Legend, thank you.

Comment: To do this in a shell script (to find the path to your shell binary; not the script's path) you can run `readlink /proc/${$}/exe` - to make sure it's not a symlink, you can do `readlink -f` instead. Just remember that readlink isn't really a "POSIX" standard command. parsing `file` might work but I'm not sure if its output is strictly standardized. Should work on systems with GNU coreutils, though (most of them).

Comment: I'm getting `/proc/24076/exe: broken symbolic link to /newroot/app/bin/slade` What does that mean?

Answer (score 18):

Maybe `which` is what you are looking for. For instance, on my system

```
which firefox
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/firefox
```

See also [Find Path of Application Running on Solaris, Ubuntu, Suse or Redhat Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/find-path-of-application-running-on-solaris-ubuntu-suse-or-redhat-linux/) .

Comment: `which` is cool, but it only returns programs in your $PATH. If I run `RandomProgramIDownloadedToErisKnowsWhere.bin`, this won't be of much use.

Answer (score 8):

Providing you've a process ID available, you can use:

```
readlink -f /proc/$pid/exe
```

(replace `$pid` by the process ID of a process)

If the process is not owned by you, you'll have to put `sudo` in front of it.

An example for determining the location of the command `firefox`:

1. The output of `ps ax -o pid,cmd | grep firefox` :

   ```
   22831 grep --color=auto firefox
   28179 /usr/lib/firefox-4.0.1/firefox-bin
   ```
2. `28179` is the process ID, so you've to run:

   ```
   readlink -f /proc/28179/exe
   ```

   which outputs:

   ```
   /usr/bin/firefox
   ```

Comment: You can do cool things with `/proc/$pid/exe`, if the binary is accidentally deleted, you can restore it with: `dd if=/proc/$pid/exe of=restored-binary`

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
ls -al /proc/{pid}/fd
```

and then check the output

This will list all the files your process is associated with...

Comment: Could you please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1052007/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

All the commands in the other answers are good, but you could do even more - seeing how some process has been actually run before it got to the process list.

Run in terminal:

```
top
```

And while it is running, press keyboard `C` and you will get a command of the processes that was run.